# How is the Acumatica mobile app login timeout triggered and configured

Tags: mobile, acumatica

What are the default mobile app login timeout settings?  Are these tied to device OS events, or something else?  Does anyone know the details on this, or where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Mobile App is using a similar session as the Website, so the timeout is shared and configured in the web.config by the `sessionState` and `formsAuth` sections.

> `<sessionState timeout="60"\>`
>
> By default, the session time-out is set to 60 minutes.

> `<formsAuth loginUrl="Frames/Login.aspx" timeout="60" /\>`
>
> By default, the cookie time-out is set to 60 minutes.

[To Configure the Session Time-Out](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=54775fb6-60d7-4995-99c0-8349f9b5d356)